# How to select a column from different table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have two tables that are arduino_id and tb_device. I want to select all the column from arduino_id and one column on tb_device. How do I do that?

[table: arduino_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG3sp.png)

[table: device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXJuQ.png)

I've tried this query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT a.id_node, a.name_node, a.volt, a.temp_udara, a.humid, a.arus, a.luminance, a.coord, a.kwh, a.bck, a.date_server FROM arduino_id a JOIN tb_device d ON a.name_node = d.nama_device
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use * for all columns from *arduino_id* and the column name for the one from *tb_device*

```
SELECT a.*, 
       d.nama_device 
FROM arduino_id a 
JOIN tb_device d ON a.name_node = d.nama_device
```

Comment: You could, but there is no need to replace the proper column selection by *

Comment: True but won't return anything because join condition is wrong

Comment: the query works but return nothing

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah it returns nothing